# Need help with the follow lemma in Sylow theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Lemma Let G be a finite group and let $P$ be a p-subgroup of $G$, i.e. a subgroup of $G$ which is a p-group. Then 
$$[N_G(P):P]\equiv [G:P] \mod p$$

Proof: Consider the action of $G$ on $X=G/P$ by left multiplication: $a*gP=agP$. We restrict this action to an action of $P$ on $G/P$. For this action we have $(G/P)^P=N_G(P)/P$. In fact, for $gP \in G/P$ one has

$gP \in (G/P)^P \leftrightarrow agP=gP$ for all $a \in P \leftrightarrow g^{-1}ag \in P \text{ How?}$ for all $a \in P$

$\leftrightarrow a \in gPg^{-1}$ for all $a \in P$ $\leftrightarrow P\leq gPg^{-1}$ How? $\leftrightarrow P=gPg^{-1}$ How?

$\leftrightarrow g \in N_G(P) \leftrightarrow gP \in N_G(P)/P$  HOW?

Now, Corollary 11.12 implies this result

Let $G$ be a p group and and let $X$ be a finite G set. Then

$$|X^G| \equiv |X| \text{ }\mod p$$

Basically I don't understand the whole proof. It would be nice if someone explains the details. There are a lot of things that are obvious to the author which I don't get.

I always have asked myself why $gHg^{-1} \in P$ implies $H \in g^{-1}Pg$

Why do we treat inclusion like equality because it looks like we can multiply on both sides like we do with an equality?

Comment: What means $(G/P)^{P}$?

Comment: hey raph, the set of P fixed points of $G/P$ basically for any element x in $G/P$ one has $g*x=x$ for all $g \in P$

Comment: I guess it denotes the set of fixed points under the action of $P$.

Comment: Maybe with slightly more verbosity it will be clearer: $agP = gP \iff g^{-1}agP = P \iff g^{-1}ag \in P$. Multiply this on the left by $g$ and on the right by $g^{-1}$ to show that it is equivalent to $a \in gPg^{-1}$. This is true for all $a \in P$, so $P \leq gPg^{-1}$. Since $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ have the same size, and $P$ is contained in $gPg^{-1}$, this forces $P = gPg^{-1}$. This shows that $g$ normalizes $P$, hence $g \in N_G(P)$, so $gP$ is in $N_G(P)/P$. I dropped some of the "iffs", but you can verify that each step is reversible.

Comment: Why is $P$ contained in $gPg^{-1}$?

Comment: Before that why $g^{-1}agP=P$ implies $g^{-1}ag \in P$?

Comment: Because $e\in P$.

Comment: so $g^{-1}ag=e$

Comment: No $g^{-1}ag e\in P$.

Comment: @daniel $g^{-1}agP = P$ means that $g^{-1}agP$, which is the coset of $P$ containing $g^{-1}ag$, is $P$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if $agP=gP\Leftrightarrow\exists x,y\in P \ ;agx=gy \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}ag=yx^{-1}\in P$, i.e., $agP=gP\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}ag\in P$.

The other cases are similar.

Comment: UMMM got it. If you see Bungo's answer, he says that we can multiply your final result on the left by g and on the right by $g^{-1}$. My question is why are we allowed to do that. why do we treat inclusion like an equality?

Comment: Think of "multiplying by $g$" as a function from $G$ to $G$. For any function $f$, if $S \subseteq T$, then $f(S) \subseteq f(T)$.

Comment: Next argument why is $P$ a subgroup of $gPg^{-1}$?

Comment: @daniel we do not treat inclusion as equality. You can use similar arguments to those shown to justify this things.

Now, note that, for a group be a subgroup of a group (both contained in a bigger group) is necessary and sufficient that it is a subset of the group. This justifies $P$ be a subgroups of $gPg^{-1}$.

Comment: OHH I didn't know that, so if it's subset of a group  then it's automatically a subgroup

Comment: @daniel yes. A subgroup is a subset which is a group.

Comment: @daniel A subset of a group is not automatically a subgroup. But in this case $a \in gPg^{-1}$ for every $a \in P$, so $P$ is a subset of $gPg^{-1}$. Since we already know that $P$ is a group (it is a subgroup of $G$), this means that $P$ is a subgroup of $gPg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

> For $gP \in G/P$ one has
>
> $gP \in (G/P)^P \leftrightarrow agP=gP$ for all $a \in P $

That's the definition of a  fixed point under the action of $P$.

> $\leftrightarrow g^{-1}ag \in P \text{ How?}$ for all $a \in P$

Multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$.

> $\leftrightarrow a \in gPg^{-1}$ for all $a \in P$ $\leftrightarrow
> > P\leq gPg^{-1}$ How?

Take the inverse automorphism of conjugation by $g$, which is conjugation by $g^{-1}$. This proves every element of $P$ is in  $gPg^{-1}$, whence the inclusion.

> $\leftrightarrow P=gPg^{-1}$ How?

$P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ have the same  number of elements, since the latter is the isomorphic image of the former. As one contains the other, they're actually equal.

> $\leftrightarrow g \in N_G(P) \leftrightarrow gP \in N_G(P)/P$  HOW?

The first equivalence corresponds to the definition of the normaliser of $P$ in $G$. The second equivalence corresponds to the definition of the quotient group $N_G(P)/P$.

> I always have asked myself why $gHg^{-1} \in P$ implies $H \in
> > g^{-1}Pg$

Always the inverse automorphism. But you should use $\subset$, not $\in$.

Comment: In your third line. Why is it a subgroup?. By the way, excellent answer.

Comment: *What* is a subgroup?

Comment: It has to hold certain axioms to be a subgroup. An earlier question is why is $gPg^{-1}$ a group

Comment: A subset of a group is considered a subgroup if it has the identity element of its parent group, It's close and it has an inverse for every element in the subset

Comment: Oh! That's because it's the image of the subgroup $P$ by a homomorphism (conjugation by $g$).

Comment: what is a subgroup for you. It looks like I am missing a corollary of the main definition

Comment: Same definition as yours. It's one of the first basic results on groups that the image of  a (sub)group by a homomorphism is a subgroup of the codomain.

Comment: OHHHHHHH yes, if you define a homomorphism $f$ from $G$ to $G$ then f(G) is a subgroup of G. In this case conjugation is a homomorphism right?

Comment: @daniel Even better, conjugation is a bijective homomorphism, i.e. an isomorphism!

Comment: but that would show $gag^{-1}$ is a subgroup of G. How do we show p is a subgroup of $gag^{-1}$?